# kotlin/android studio: wait for button to be pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, wait

so i am writing an app that asks the user to identify different notes that are being played to them. i imagine that to be done by playing one random note from a set of notes, then waiting for the user to press a button with the corresponding note, telling the user whether they put in the correct note, and, after a short delay, start the whole thing anew.

now my problem is the part with "waiting for the user to press the button".

Heres what i have done so far:

I have 12 buttons, one for each note of the chromatic scale, each with a corresponding onClickListener looking like this

```
        dobutton.setOnClickListener {
            var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cping)
            mediaPlayer?.start()
            givenAnswer = 4 // etc. for all the other notes.
```

I then introduce some variables:

```
        var score = 0
        var index = 0
        var setAnswer = 0
        var givenAnswer = 0
```

I then have this while loop that ends after a number of rounds played and includes firstly this section that randomly selects one of the notes for playback and sets a correct answer, with corresponding files for playback and values for setAnswer for each note of the chromatic scale...

```
while (index != 11) {

    val randomGenerator = Random()
    val randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(11)

    when (randomInt) {
        0 ->{
            var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abping)
            mediaPlayer?.start()
            println(pingsArray[0])
            setAnswer = 0
        }
        1 -> {
            var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aping)
            mediaPlayer?.start()
            println(pingsArray[1])
            setAnswer = 1
        } // etc. for all the other notes...
```

...and then this block that compares the correct answer and the one given and increments the values accordingly.

```
run {
        if (setAnswer == givenAnswer) {
            index = index + 1
            score = score + 1
        }
        else {
            index = index + 1
        }
    }
}
```

After this, the while loop should begin anew. Then the whole thing presents the score.

Now my problem is that the whole while loop executes in one go, without giving the user any time to respond to anything. After spending a whole day googling and finding nothing useful, I finally decided to ask here. In case that it shows all too much: I just started coding a few days ago so please have mercy if my questions are a bit stupid and my code does not comply to the standards. It´s just a whole bunch of complicated stuff when you´re new to it...

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to put a delay in the while loop before it goes back and runs the code again?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. Just that it´s not a delay with a fixed time but one that is over when a button is pressed.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to run the piece of code once the button it clicked? You can accumulate the int + 1 every time the button is clicked?

Comment: `var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer?` why not `val mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer`?

Comment: @ EpicPandaForce: to be honest, I don´t know. I just googled for a line i could use to start playing the sounds. It worked, so I kept it. Android Studio told me I could use val instead of var, but I couldn´t see a benefit from that.

Comment: @ Nero : That would be possible, but wouldn´t that just delay my problem until the code has run the first time?

Comment: @BraveSentry you can put the code within onCreate method so it only gets triggered once. Then it will get triggered every time when the user hits the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply intend to continuously wait until a user has clicked a button before playing the next sound, then honestly on each of your onClick listeners just add a new call to your function that generates the next media play (let's call it `playNextSound()`) and immediately compare the result, for example:

```
dobutton.setOnClickListener {
    val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cping)
    mediaPlayer.start()

    index += 1
    if(setAnswer == thisButton){
        score += 1
    }

    if(index < 11){
        playNextSound()
    } else {
        showResults()
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you intend to have some sort of a timeout, then that's a slightly different story. You may want to take advantage of a few asynchronous solutions to get around your conundrum: [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) or more advanced [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) & Runnable solution.

For the former, you can declare a timer that countdown to a specific time after the music is played, like so:

```
var timeoutCountdown: CountDownTimer = object: CountdownTimer(timeInMills, timeInMills) {

    override fun onFinish() {
        //Do something to inform the user he has run out of time. For example:
        showErrorDialog()
        index += 1
        if(index < 11){
            playNextSound()
        } else {
            showResults()
        }
    }

    override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
        //Ignore, unless you want to do something here.   
    }
}
```

and then in `playNextSound()` itself, after playing the sound, call `timeoutCountdown.start()`. Then, in each of the `onClickListener`s, do the same thing as the simpler implementation above and just add one line:

```
dobutton.setOnClickListener {
    //ADD THIS LINE TO STOP THE COUNTDOWN
    try { timeoutCountdown.cancel() } catch(ignored: Exception){}

    val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cping)
    mediaPlayer.start()

    index += 1
    if(setAnswer == thisButton){
        score += 1
    }

    if(index < 11){
        playNextSound()
    } else {
        showResults()
    }
}
```

If you are keen to use a `Handler`/Runnable situation instead which is really overkill if just for this use, do let me know and I'll add it in.

EDIT: Using this implementation there is no need for a `while` loop anymore; you're using the functions and the event trigger (`onClickListener` or `CountDownTimer`) as the control flow.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! Turns out using a while loop was the wrong approach altogether and using CountDownTimer and onClickListener seems to get the job done.